# Angular 6 dynamic form with multiple form group

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am building a dynamic form using Angular 6. Please find here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-dynamic-form-ovyftx

But on submit not getting form values in proper format. I am getting like

```
{"group1":{"brave":"","firstName":"Bombasto","emailAddress":"","multiBox":""},"group2":{"brave":"","firstName":"Bombasto","emailAddress":"","multiBox":""}}
```

I should get like

```
{"group1":{"brave":"","firstName":"Bombasto"},"group2":{"emailAddress":"","multiBox":""}}
```

Because fields belong to different group. How to fix this? Also how can i validate form on group basis. like if one field is invalid , that group should get a red border.

Answer (score 1):

You did a small mistake on your service question-control.service. You are adding the new control to the same variable "group". so on the second loop, your previous controls are also added to it. Just reset its value on next loop. You are good to go for your first problem.

```
Object.keys(questions).forEach((eachgroup: string) => {
    group = {}; //here you new to reset the value of group
    questions[eachgroup].forEach(question => {
      group[question.key] = question.required ? new FormControl(question.value || '', Validators.required)
        : new FormControl(question.value || '');
    });
    sections[eachgroup] = new FormGroup(group);
  });
```

And for the validation part, you can use [ngClass] directive and apply your custom css for invalid  input like below:

```
    <div [formGroup]="form" [ngClass]="{'isa_error':isValid?false:true}">
        <label [attr.for]="question.key">{{question.label}}</label>
....
</div>
```

Working Code Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-dynamic-form-wvspuw

App: https://angular6-dynamic-form-wvspuw.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this [stackblitz-angular-formgroup-as-array](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup-as-array?file=app%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts). Simplified example of formArray.

So in my example, it would be:

```js
form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  tops: this.fb.array([])
}, {
  validator: this.exampleValidator
});

exampleValidator(e) {
  //does logic for validity on form
  console.log(e);
}
```

```js
export class SelectMultipleExample implements OnInit {


  form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    tops: this.fb.array([])
  });

  toppingList = [{
      id: 0,
      name: 'Extra cheese'
    },
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Mushroom'
    },
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Onion'
    },
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Pepperoni'
    },
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Sausage'
    },
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Tomato'
    }
  ];

  complexOrderToppings = [{
      order: {
        selected: [{
            id: 0,
            name: "Extra cheese"
          },
          {
            id: 0,
            name: "Mushroom"
          },
          {
            id: 0,
            name: "Onion"
          },
          {
            id: 0,
            name: "Pepperoni"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      order: {
        selected: [{
            id: 0,
            name: "Extra cheese"
          },
          {
            id: 0,
            name: "Mushroom"
          },
          {
            id: 0,
            name: "Onion"
          },
          {
            id: 0,
            name: "Pepperoni"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      order: {
        selected: [{
            id: 0,
            name: "Extra cheese"
          },
          {
            id: 0,
            name: "Mushroom"
          },
          {
            id: 0,
            name: "Onion"
          },
          {
            id: 0,
            name: "Pepperoni"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ];

  simpleOrderToppings = [{
      order: [{
          id: 0,
          name: "Extra cheese"
        },
        {
          id: 0,
          name: "Mushroom"
        },
        {
          id: 0,
          name: "Onion"
        },
        {
          id: 0,
          name: "Pepperoni"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      order: [{
          id: 0,
          name: "Extra cheese"
        },
        {
          id: 0,
          name: "Mushroom"
        },
        {
          id: 0,
          name: "Onion"
        },
        {
          id: 0,
          name: "Pepperoni"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      order: [{
          id: 0,
          name: "Extra cheese"
        },
        {
          id: 0,
          name: "Mushroom"
        },
        {
          id: 0,
          name: "Onion"
        },
        {
          id: 0,
          name: "Pepperoni"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setToppings(this.complexOrderToppings);
  }

  get getTops(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('tops') as FormArray;
  }

  setToppings(toppings: any) {
    const toppingsFGs = toppings.map(topping => this.fb.group(topping));
    const topppingFormArray = this.fb.array(toppingsFGs);
    this.form.setControl('tops', topppingFormArray);
    this.setTopsNewValue();
  }

  compareSelected(o1: any, o2: any): boolean {
    if (!o1 || !o2) {
      return false;
    }
    const isSelected = o1.name === o2.name && o1.id === o2.id;
    return isSelected;
  }

  setTopsNewValue() {
    const tops = this.getTops;
    tops.controls.map(t => {
      const newValue = t.value.order.selected;
      t.setValue({
        order: newValue
      });
    });
  }
}


/**  Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="tops">
    <div *ngFor="let top of getTops.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select [placeholder]="'Selected Toppings ' + (i + 1)" formControlName="order" multiple [compareWith]="compareSelected">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">
            {{topping.name}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<pre>{{form.value | json}}</pre>
```